# Actions not working (Do Calculation, Send an email, etc)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list

So I want to make a new workflow from Sharepoint list. After I put the condition, I want to put an action like Do Calculation, but when I choose the choice Action ribbon -> Do Calculation, it doesn't appear to do anything. I keep seeing "start typing or use the insert group on the ribbon workflow action sharepoint".

Same thing happened when I type Do Calculation, it keep showing this "start typing or use the insert group on the ribbon workflow action sharepoint". I also tried another action like add comment, delete item, etc, still the same thing happened. I've already open the application as administrator. I have no clue why it happened, I've also re-install it.

Any help is appreciated, sorry for my bad english. Thank you in advance.

(I am using sharepoint 2013 and sharepoint designer 2013)

When I try to click the choice on Actions ribbon

[image]

Then after that it won't proceed and show anything particular
[image]

Same thing happened when I try to type the Actions like do calculation
[image]

When I press enter, it doesn't show anything particular too
[image]

Comment: Can you add a video?

Comment: @AlexeyKrasheninnikov I'm sorry I am unable to add the video, but I already added some images to describe the problem. thank you.

Comment: Looks like a local SPDESIGN.EXE issue. Can you try to clean the cache folders (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`
 and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`)? Can you reproduce this on another client workstation and/or another server? Can you check Application.evtx event log entries on the client machine and/or trace web interactions using Fiddler?